# Prolog - working out average of every 2 elements in a list

Tags: list, prolog

I've been working on a Prolog assignment and one of the questions has completely baffled me.

Question: Define a predicate adjAve(L,Ave),  that is true when Ave contains the list of the averages  of each consecutive two numbers in list L. If the list L contains an odd number of elements the last one is ignored.

For example, the following query should give this result:

```
?-adjAve([4,6,7,20,9],A).
A=[5.0,13.5].
```

Currently I have:

```
 adjAve([X,Y|Tail], Ave) :-
   X \= [], Y \= [],
   Ave is ((X+Y)/2).
```

Currently when I type this query:

```
?- adjAve([1,2,3,4,5], X).
X = 1.5.
```

I get the average of the first 2 values in the list. Now, how do I get the average of the next 2 values (3 and 4) and display that?

The answer I need to display for the above query should be:

```
X = [1.5,3.5]
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 3):

This problem could easily be cast as a DCG (Definite Clause Grammar). The DCG equivalent of @repeat's answer would be:

```
avgs([]) --> [] | [_].
avgs([A|As]) --> [X, Y], { A is (X + Y)/2 }, avgs(As).

adjAve(L, A) :-
   phrase(avgs(A), L).
```

Comment: s(X): With DCG, I like using the bar for expressing alternatives. `avgs([]) --> [] | [_].`

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track!

```
adjAve([] ,[]).
adjAve([_],[]).              % ignore last singleton item, if present
adjAve([X,Y|XYs],[A|As]) :-
   A is (X+Y)/2,
   adjAve(XYs,As).
```

Sample queries, as given by the OP:

```
?- adjAve([4,6,7,20,9],A).
A = [5, 13.5].               % note: the first average is integer

?- adjAve([1,2,3,4,5], X).
X = [1.5, 3.5].
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a more principled approach possible?

Comment: @false. By using the right meta-predicate(s)?  Now *that* I want! I considered using `combine/3`, but ignoring the last list item (of odd-lengthed lists) was in the way...

Comment: Not sure, just a gut feeling